# How can I call back a function after it returns a value in C

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I wrote a program that uses 2d arrays.
I have 2 functions, one is presenting a menu of options (I didn't cover most of them), the menu calls the other function.

that function is implementing one of the menu's options, which is buying a seat in a theater, if the seat that the user wants is taken, then the function returns `0` and if it is not taken, it returns `1` and changes the value of the seat to `-1`. The situation is when the function returns a value, it ends, I know why, but how can I re-use it again?

Here is the code for the menu:

```
void menu(int cinema[][SEATS_IN_ROW])
{
    int choice = 0;
    printf("Select an option:\n1 - Print cinema hall\n2 - Buy a ticket\n3 - Print number of taken seats\n4 - Make a seat discount\n5 - Set a new price for all seats\n6 - Exit\n");
    scanf("%d", &choice);

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
        printCinema(cinema, ROWS);
        break;

        case 2:
        if(ticket(cinema) == 0)
        {
            printf("Seat taken!");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("You got the seat!");
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the second function (buying a seat):

```
   int ticket(int cinema[][SEATS_IN_ROW])
{   
    int rows = 0 , cols = 0;
    int flag = 0;

    printf("Which row (0-4)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Which seat (0-2)?\n");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    if(cinema[rows][cols] == -1)
    {
        flag = 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cinema[rows][cols] = -1;
        flag = 1;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: when calling any of the `scanf()` family of functions, always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: when getting input from the user, ALWAYS check that input to be sure it contains a valid value.

Comment: for these kinds of numbers: `printf("Which row (0-4)?\n");` suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code

Comment: when writing a `switch()` statement, include a `default` case for when the user enters some unexpected value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a loop in `menu()`, so that it keeps on running until the users tells it to exit.

Comment: Or, possibly, have a loop _around_ the call to `menu()`.(until `menu` returns a value indicating the user chose "Quit").